# AWS Cloudformation with AWS SAM cli - is it possible to rollback?

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-cloudformation

After updating a cloudformation stack via `sam build`, `sam package` and `sam deploy` is it possible to rollback to the previous configuration?

##### My use case

I've set up a Gitlab project with the Cloudformation template and a pipeline to manage deployments and integration.
I want to update a development stack on a merge request to check that new architecture is ok, run some integration test (e.g. making somme calls to the cloudfront distribution or send some sns message) and then if something went wrong during deployment and/or testing rollback the update to previous stable state.
If everything goes well, the MR is then merged and the changes are applied to the pre-prod stack.